# Оставить комментарий в Telegram-канале с помощью TLSharp

Tags: c#, telegram, tlsharp

В Telegram есть комментарии, комментарии — это сообщения в чате, связанном с каналом.

Могу написать сообщение в чат:

[messages.sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage)

```cs
private async Task SendMessage(TLAbsInputPeer to, string message, int? replyMsgId = null)
{
    var req = new TLRequestSendMessage()
    {
        Peer = to,
        Message = message,
        RandomId = Helpers.GenerateRandomLong(),
        ReplyToMsgId = replyMsgId
    };
    await _client.SendRequestAsync<TLUpdates>(req);
}
```

Как можно оставить комментарий под сообщением в канале?
Насколько я понимаю API для них есть: [api для комментариев?](https://core.telegram.org/api/threads)

Как это можно реализовать?

Моих навыков работы с Telegram недостаточно для того, чтобы с ними разобраться.